# Cordova Security Paches

Tags: android, security, cordova, patch

We are using Cordova 2.4 for Android. Several CVE vulnerabilities have just been fixed in 3.5.1 and greater:

- CVE-2014-3500
- CVE-2014-3501
- CVE-2014-3502

Can anyone point me to the Cordova patches for these issues? I'd like to see if I can backport the patches to Cordova 2.4.

Thanks, Brian

Answer (score 0):

It's not a small patch that can be easily cherry-picked. The vulnerability fix relies on new function that was added after 2.4. It really is recommended to upgrade to Cordova 3.5.1 or later. Unless you are doing something unusual, it really will be easier to upgrade to 3.5.1 than to backport to 2.4.

Answer (score 0):

**How to patch CVE-2014-3500: quick fix of the latest Cordova vulnerability:**

To fix it, find every exported Activity, that call WebView.loadUrl() API.

Locate the place where the Activity is instantiated and clean ‘url’ and ‘errorUrl’, provided by a caller. I skipped the part on errorUrl, as they are very similar.

You should add the following lines just before the first call of super.loadUrl():

**super.setStringProperty("url", null); 
super.setStringProperty("errorUrl",null);**

I gave more details here:
http://crocode.blogspot.ru/2014/10/how-to-patch-cve-2014-3500-quick-fix-of.html